# Amazon S3 "NoSuchFieldError: REQUIRES_LENGTH" for putObject in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to write a JSON object to S3. I have AWS credentials set up on my Eclipse IDE, and they work properly with my code that interacts with DynamoDB - these credentials have full access to AWS.

I'm using the AWS provided example code here: https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/java/example_code/s3/src/main/java/aws/example/s3/PutObject.java

but for some reason I keep getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: REQUIRES_LENGTH
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1708)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1680)
at com.javapapers.webservices.rest.jersey.metrics.DailyMetricsReportWriter.writeReportToS3(DailyMetricsReportWriter.java:42)
at com.javapapers.webservices.rest.jersey.metrics.MetricsServiceTest.shoutsAndSessionsForWriter(MetricsServiceTest.java:68)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:39)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:79)
at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:70)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:89)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
at     org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

Any ideas?

I read somewhere else on here that the apache http-core library was needed, so I added that but it still doesn't work.

I've also tried creating a file in the method and passing that in, but that doesn't work.

I used an example that set the object metadata to have length in it, but that also didn't work.

I'm out of ideas!

```
public String writeReportToS3(DailyMetricsReport report) {
        String bucket_name = "existing_bucket";
        String file_path = "new_file_name";
        String key_name = Paths.get(file_path).getFileName().toString();

        System.out.format("Uploading %s to S3 bucket %s...\n", file_path, bucket_name);
        final AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient();
        try {
            s3.putObject(bucket_name, key_name, new File(file_path));
        } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getErrorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }

    return "done!";
}
```

Comment: Please provide your AWS library dependencies and versions.

Comment: @Compass aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.477.jar, aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.477.jar, aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.592.jar are all the AWS libraries in the build path

Comment: @Compass I updated my aws-java-sdk-core to also be 1.11.592 but that hasn't changed anything unfortunately

Comment: You may need to do a dependency-tree on your dependencies to see if an out of date jar is being pulled in for AWS

Answer (score 4):

## The right solution:

> To select individual SDK modules, use the AWS SDK for Java bill of materials (BOM) for Maven, which will ensure that the modules you specify use the same version of the SDK and that they're compatible with each other.
>
> You can now select individual modules from the SDK that you use in your application. Because you already declared the SDK version in the BOM, you don't need to specify the version number for each component.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/setup-project-maven.html#configuring-maven-individual-components

```
<project>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.11.615</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

A simple way to check what happens: `mvnw dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=com.amazonaws`

In this case (bom: `1.11.615`) the highest compatible version for each component is `1.11.415`:

```
[INFO] +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:jar:1.11.415:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kms:jar:1.11.415:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.11.415:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.amazonaws:jmespath-java:jar:1.11.415:compile
[INFO] \- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:jar:1.11.415:compile
```

**NOTE**. Check AWS SDK for Java version 2:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/setup-project-maven.html#configuring-maven-individual-components
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/migration-guide/whats-different.html

---

### Don't do it in production:

You can also take the risk on yourself and force your own dependencies:

```
<project>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.615</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-kms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmespath-java</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.615</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmespath-java</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.615</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-kms</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.615</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmespath-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.615</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Now you get: `mvnw dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=com.amazonaws`

```
[INFO] +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:jar:1.11.615:compile
[INFO] +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:jar:1.11.615:compile
[INFO] +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.11.615:compile
[INFO] +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kms:jar:1.11.615:compile
[INFO] \- com.amazonaws:jmespath-java:jar:1.11.615:compile
```

...and now you should run some serious tests :(